# Erlang SASL GSSAPI error: Cannot contact any KDC for realm

Tags: erlang, kerberos, sasl, gssapi

Sorry, if I'm not providing the right detail, I'm fairly new at this and it's the first time I'm trying to consume from kafka through kerberos authentication.
I'm using the brod_gssapi ([https://github.com/kafka4beam/brod_gssapi.git]) so that I can connect with Brod to kafka using sasl gssapi authentication.
The code is running under red hat linux 7.9.

That realm is defined under my **krb5.conf**, which is located under **/etc**
I have also set this environment variable: **export KAFKA_OPTS="-Djava.security.krb5.conf=/etc/krb5.conf"**

I have also installed the proper dependencies to use with brod_gssapi:
**cyrus-sasl-devel,
cyrus-sasl-libs,
cyrus-sasl-gssapi,
krb5-devel krb5-libs**

Do I need to load this file somewhere else?

These are the line of codes that I'm currently running in erlang:

```
Config =
    [
      {ssl, true},
      {sasl, {callback, brod_gssapi, {gssapi, <<"FileKeytab.keytab">>, <<"username@BELL.CORP.BCE.CA">>}}}
    ].
Args =
    [
      {bootstrap_endpoints, [{"server_name", port}]},
      {topic, <<"topic_name">>},
      {partition, all},
      {config, Config},
      {begin_offset, latest},
      {client_id, test_kafka}
    ].

Bootstrap_endpoints = proplists:get_value(bootstrap_endpoints, Args),
Topic = proplists:get_value(topic, Args),
Config = proplists:get_value(config, Args),
Partition = proplists:get_value(partition, Args),
Begin_offset = proplists:get_value(begin_offset, Args),
Client_id = proplists:get_value(client_id, Args).

{ok, _} = application:ensure_all_started(brod).
ok = application:load(brod_gssapi).
application:set_env(brod_gssapi,default_handshake_vsn,1).
ok = brod:start_client(Bootstrap_endpoints, Client_id, Config).
```

After running the last line of code, I get the error below:
The realm **BELLDEV.DEV.BCE.CA** is defined under the krb5.conf file.
Any insight you might have would really help.

Thank you!

```
   {{sasl_auth_error,{sasl_fail,<<"SASL(-1): generic failure: GSSAPI Error: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information (Cannot contact any KDC for realm 'BELLDEV.DEV.BCE.CA')">>}},
    [{kpro_sasl,auth,7,
               [{file,"/home/med/bm/ossfm/server/fm/_build/default/lib/kafka_protocol/src/kpro_sasl.erl"},
                {line,43}]},
    {kpro_connection,init_connection,2,
                     [{file,"/home/med/bm/ossfm/server/fm/_build/default/lib/kafka_protocol/src/kpro_connection.erl"},
                      {line,240}]},
    {kpro_connection,init,4,
                     [{file,"/home/med/bm/ossfm/server/fm/_build/default/lib/kafka_protocol/src/kpro_connection.erl"},
                      {line,170}]},
    {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,247}]}]}}],
[{brod_client,ensure_metadata_connection,1,
              [{file,"/home/med/bm/ossfm/server/fm/_build/default/lib/brod/src/brod_client.erl"},
               {line,554}]},
 {brod_client,handle_info,2,
              [{file,"/home/med/bm/ossfm/server/fm/_build/default/lib/brod/src/brod_client.erl"},
               {line,300}]},
 {gen_server,try_dispatch,4,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,616}]},
 {gen_server,handle_msg,6,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,686}]},
 {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,247}]}]}
```

Comment: _Can_ you actually contact the KDC? Are you able to get initial tickets with `kinit`?

Comment: Hi, Yes, when I do `kinit`, with the keytab and principle, I do get the "Authenticated to Kerberos v5" message. The krb5.conf also have the realm BELL.CORP.BCE.CA and BELLDEV.DEV.BCE.CA defined.